# R convert dataframe with character lists to list with correct R types efficiently

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, lapply

I use crateDB to load a table as a dataframe into R. The problem is, that crateDB sends arrays as a comma separated string. Therefore I want to convert all arrays to the correct R type. I also want to convert the dataframe to a list, since its possible to use objects in crateDB, which wouldn't work with a dataframe.
This conversion is too slow at the moment, so I tried several things to improve the performance.

If I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  position = c(
    "{\"82.81864\",\"82.586235\",\"82.35383\"}",
    "{\"83.81864\",\"83.586235\",\"83.35383\"}",
    "{\"84.81864\",\"84.586235\",\"84.35383\"}",
    "{\"85.81864\",\"85.586235\",\"85.35383\"}",
    "{\"86.81864\",\"86.586235\",\"86.35383\"}",
    "{\"87.81864\",\"87.586235\",\"87.35383\"}",
    "{\"88.81864\",\"88.586235\",\"88.35383\"}",
    "{\"89.81864\",\"89.586235\",\"89.35383\"}",
    "{\"90.81864\",\"90.586235\",\"90.35383\"}",
    "{\"91.81864\",\"91.586235\",\"91.35383\"}"
  ),
  vcontrol = c(
    "{\"t\",\"t\",\"t\",\"t\"}","{\"f\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
    "{\"f\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
    "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
    "{\"t\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
    "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"f\"}"
  )
)
```

The resulting list after conversion should look like this:
[image: converted_list]

I started with two for loops, which were really slow for big datasets. Then I tried the apply functions:

```
convertDF = function(dataFrame, dataTypes){
  dimension <- dim(x = dataFrame)
  names <- names(x = dataFrame)
  
  asList <- lapply(dataFrame, as.list)
  
  for(row in seq_len(length(asList))){
    asList[[row]] <- lapply(asList[[x]], convertToRType, type = dataTypes[row])
  }
  
  data <- list()
  for(datarow in seq_len(dimension[1])){
    tempData <- list()
    for(datacol in seq_len(dimension[2])){
      tempData[[names[datacol]]] <- asList[[datacol]][[datarow]]
    }
    data[[datarow]] <- tempData
  }
  return(data)
}
```

The convertToRType function uses the type that is used in the database as a parameter, so it can tell wether to convert it to an integer, double or logical. I do this with if identical checks. For arrays I first remove all unneeded characters, split at , and then use as.double over the entire vector for example.

```
  data <- str_replace_all(
    string = rawData,
    pattern = c("\\{" = "", "\\}" = "", "\"" = "")
  )
  data <- str_split(string = data, pattern = ",")[[1]]
```

I did this, because I wanted to use the multithreading capabilities of lapply, but turns out its even slower on windows. But with this function the conversion only took half as long as before. I still don't like this solution, though. The code isn't clean and doesn't seem to be a good performance.

Can anybody tell me how to do this conversion as efficiently as possible? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What is the final result expected to look like? Looks like you're growing the `data` object, which is a big no-no.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the final result is shown in the picture. Its a 2D list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` to do the conversions to right types inside the dataframe and then `purrr` to `transpose` to list and `simplify`.  Watch out for "gotchas" like "t" <> `TRUE`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
x <- 
   df %>% 
   mutate(position = str_replace_all(
      string = .$position,
      pattern = c("\\{" = "", "\\}" = "", "\"" = "")
   ) %>% str_split(string = ., pattern = ",")
   ) %>%
   mutate(vcontrol = str_replace_all(
      string = .$vcontrol,
      pattern = c("\\{" = "", "\\}" = "", "\"" = "")
   ) %>%
      str_replace_all(string = ., c("t" = "TRUE", 
                                             "f" = "FALSE")) %>%
      str_split(string = ., pattern = ",")) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(position = list(as.numeric(unlist(position)))) %>%
   mutate(vcontrol = list(as.logical(unlist(vcontrol))))

converted_df <- transpose(x) %>% simplify_all()
str(converted_df)
#> List of 10
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 1
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 82.8 82.6 82.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 2
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 83.8 83.6 83.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 3
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 84.8 84.6 84.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 4
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 85.8 85.6 85.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 5
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 86.8 86.6 86.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 6
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 87.8 87.6 87.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 7
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 88.8 88.6 88.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 8
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 89.8 89.6 89.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 9
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 90.8 90.6 90.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ id      : num 10
#>   ..$ position: num [1:3] 91.8 91.6 91.4
#>   ..$ vcontrol: logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Your data

```r
df <- data.frame(
   id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
   position = c(
      "{\"82.81864\",\"82.586235\",\"82.35383\"}",
      "{\"83.81864\",\"83.586235\",\"83.35383\"}",
      "{\"84.81864\",\"84.586235\",\"84.35383\"}",
      "{\"85.81864\",\"85.586235\",\"85.35383\"}",
      "{\"86.81864\",\"86.586235\",\"86.35383\"}",
      "{\"87.81864\",\"87.586235\",\"87.35383\"}",
      "{\"88.81864\",\"88.586235\",\"88.35383\"}",
      "{\"89.81864\",\"89.586235\",\"89.35383\"}",
      "{\"90.81864\",\"90.586235\",\"90.35383\"}",
      "{\"91.81864\",\"91.586235\",\"91.35383\"}"
   ),
   vcontrol = c(
      "{\"t\",\"t\",\"t\",\"t\"}","{\"f\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
      "{\"f\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
      "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
      "{\"t\",\"f\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}",
      "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"t\"}", "{\"t\",\"t\",\"f\",\"f\"}"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Sorry if it wasn't clear, but the goal is to convert it to a list first and then do the conversion to the correct type, since it also has to work for objects, which would be a list in the list.

Comment: I used part of your code to make mine cleaner:

`convertDF = function(dataFrame, dataTypes){
  transposedDF <- transpose(dataFrame)
  data <- list()
  
  for(x in seq_len(length(transposedDF))){
    data[[x]] <- mapply(convertToRType, transposedDF[[x]], type = dataTypes[seq_along(dataTypes)])
  }
  return(data)
}`

Comment: Glad to be helpful.  Please note that my solution still works if you have other addition columns that are lists of objects.  For example if you add 10 lm summary objects to your example data with  `obj1 <- summary(lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars))` & `df$obj1 <- list(obj1)` the code to make it list `x` still works.